# Update content in div, on click of another div

Tags: jquery

I have this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/k4ee2ugt/)

```
$('body').click(function() {
   $('#moreinfo').addClass('hidden');
   $('.trigger').parent().removeClass('active');
});

$('#moreinfo').addClass('hidden');
$('.portfoliotile .description').addClass('hidden');

$('.trigger').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#moreinfo').removeClass('hidden');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $('#details').html($(this).parent().find('.description').html());

});

$('#closegall').click(function(){
    $('#moreinfo').addClass('hidden');
    $('.portfoliotile').removeClass('dark');
});
```

When you click on a red box image, text from that red box appears in the yellow box. Also when you click on the red box image, an 'active' class is added to the red box, changing its opacity.

However, when you click on a second red box, the first red box still keeps the 'active' class, so now, both red boxes have this 'active' class.

I want to only have one 'active' class present at a time, whichever red box you click on should be the 'active' one.

If you can show me on an updated fiddle, that would be greatly appreciated as I'm learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove the active class from all the `.portfoliotile` elements when you click on a `.trigger` with `$('.portfoliotile').removeClass('active')`:

```
$('.trigger').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.portfoliotile').removeClass('active')
  $('#moreinfo').removeClass('hidden');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $('#details').html($(this).parent().find('.description').html());
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zzq8trsx/)**